# Can this secure, random generator be improved?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, random, cryptography

This random generator uses cryptographically secure numbers/chars instead of `Math.random()`. The Javascript code with jQuery works well but I affect clean code ;) It would be great if you could help me to optimize the code (e.g. in speed).

```
(function () {
    var $length, $result, $new, $chars;

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $length = $('#pw-length');
        $result = $('#pw-result');
        $new = $('#get-new-pw');
        $chars = $('#pw-chars');

        // display the result on page load
        getRandomString();
        // generate new password
        $new.click(function () {
            getRandomString();
            return false;
        });

        // allow only numbers in the length-input-field
        $length.on('keyup focusout', function () {
            $length.val($length.val().replace(/[^0-9]/g, ''));
        });
    });

    function randomString(length) {
        var charset = $chars.val(),
            length = parseInt($length.val()),
            i,
            result = "";

        // First we're going to try to use a built-in CSPRNG
        if (window.crypto && window.crypto.getRandomValues) {
            values = new Uint32Array(length);
            window.crypto.getRandomValues(values);

            for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                result += charset[values[i] % charset.length];
            }
        }

        // IE calls it msCrypto
        else if (window.msCrypto && window.msCrypto.getRandomValues) {
            values = new Uint32Array(length);
            window.msCrypto.getRandomValues(values);

            for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                result += charset[values[i] % charset.length];
            }
        }

        // -> No built-in functionality -> use the function Math.random()
        else {
            for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                result += charset[Math.floor(Math.random() * charset.length)];
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    // Display the result
    function getRandomString() {
        $result.html(randomString(10));
    }
}());
```

I also uploaded it [here](http://jsbin.com/jolot/4/watch?html,js,output) for testing.
And of course the corresponding HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="pw-chars" value="AaBbCcDdEeFfGgHhiJjKkLMmNnoPpQqRrSsTtUuVvWwXxYyZz23456789!?$%#&@^+-~*=_.,:;()" />
<input type="text" id="pw-length" value="10" />
<button id="get-new-pw">New</button>

<div id="pw-result"></div>
```

Comment: If you're concerned that the generation should be cryptographically secure, then you should not simply default to a "non-safe" behavior without informing the user about it.

Comment: @Bobby: I didn't include this part, because I think it's not necessary :)

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @Bobby. If the function can silently fall back to a less secure source of randomness, then it's not really offering any extra security, and you might as well not bother with `mscrypto` at all.

Verbesserungsvorschlag:

```
function randomString(length, allowRandomSourceFallback) {
    ...
}
```

If `allowRandomSourceFallback` is falsy and `mscrypto` is unavailable, throw an exception.

Answer (score 2):

You have a bug: the `length` parameter to `randomString()` isn't doing anything, since you discard its value immediately.  You should separate your concerns into two functions: one "pure" function that takes a `length` parameter and generates a random string of that length, and another function that does all the DOM interaction and uses the first function.

There are three repeated implementations inside `randomString()`, which is very repetitive.  Don't repeat yourself.  I repeat, don't repeat yourself.  ☺  Instead, find a way to collapse all three cases into one.

The result should be displayed using [`jQuery.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) instead of `jQuery.html()`.

```
(function () {
  var $length, $result, $new, $chars;

  $(document).ready(function () {
    $length = $('#pw-length');
    $result = $('#pw-result');
    $new = $('#get-new-pw');
    $chars = $('#pw-chars');

    // display the result on page load
    getRandomString();
    // generate new password
    $new.click(function () {
      getRandomString();
      return false;
    });

    // allow only numbers in the length-input-field
    $length.on('keyup focusout', function () {
      $length.val($length.val().replace(/[^0-9]/g, ''));
    });
  });

  // Crypto provider stub for use as a fallback
  function dumbCrypto(randomIntLimit) {
    return {
      getRandomValues: function(values) {
        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
          values[i] = Math.floor(Math.random() * randomIntLimit);
        }
      }
    };
  }

  function randomString(length, charset, allowRandomSourceFallback) {
    // Prefer to use a built-in CSPRNG.  Neither window.crypto nor
    // window.msCrypto is standard.
    var crypto = (window.crypto && window.crypto.getRandomValues) ? window.crypto :
                 (window.msCrypto && window.msCrypto.getRandomValues) ? window.msCrypto :
                 allowRandomSourceFallback ? dumbCrypto(charset.length) : null;
    if (crypto === null) {
      throw "No secure crypto provider available";
    }

    // window.crypto and window.msCrypto require a typed array (which is
    // surely supported if window.crypto or window.msCrypto is defined).
    var values = Uint32Array ? new Uint32Array(length) : new Array(length);

    crypto.getRandomValues(values);
    var result = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      result += charset[values[i] % charset.length];
    }
    return result;
  }

  // Produce and display the result
  function getRandomString() {
    $result.text(randomString($length.val(), $chars.val()));
  }
}());
```

Comment: Since you used HTML 5 in your demo, you should also take advantage of [`<input type="number">`](http://jsbin.com/jolot/6/edit?html,js,output).

Comment: Thank you so much but the code does not seem to work in (the latest) firefox and IE!? http://jsbin.com/jolot/11/watch